# proxyConsole.js:72 TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

Tags: html, css, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am new to react redux loading bar and redux forms
- on submit of a button I am trying to load the loading bar.
- but the problem is when I load the loading bar. I am getting below error
  **proxyConsole.js:72 TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined**
- I debugged and found the error comes from only in this file proxyConsole.js
- but I didn't include this file.
- all my loading bar code is in this file SyncValidationForm.js
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- so that in future I will it myself.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.
- not sure how to fix the package files error

https://codesandbox.io/s/zn812n05v4

```
const SyncValidationForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <LoadingBar />

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field
          name="username"
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label="Username"
        />
        <Field
          name="email"
          type="email"
          component={renderField}
          label="Email"
        />
        <Field name="age" type="number" component={renderField} label="Age" />
        <div>
          <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
            Submit
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            disabled={pristine || submitting}
            onClick={reset}
          >
            Clear Values
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included the component `LoadingBar` but it is not connected to the store. 
The correct usage for rendering the `LoadingBar` component can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-loading-bar#usage)

If you wish not to use the middleware, you can dispatch the action to show/hide the `LoadingBar` based on example in this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-loading-bar#usage-without-middleware). You can dispatch the action in your `handleSubmit` method.

Hope this helps!